# Flutter Port number 0 is added to url automatically

Tags: flutter, socket.io

Why it is adding port number zero at the end of url automatically using socket? How can i remove the port number. I want to run it without port number in flutter.

```
socket = io('https://SITE_DOMAIN:443',
        OptionBuilder()
          .setTransports(['websocket'])
          .build()
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the file socket_io_client.dart:49. If no port is passed then due to null safety it takes default int value 0.

For those who are looking solution for it, pass a port number while connecting. If no custom port by server, for ws pass 80 for wss pass 443.

Example:

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

  IO.Socket socket = IO.io(
  'wss://socket.example.com:443',
   IO.OptionBuilder()
      .setTransports(['websocket'])
      .build());
```